# cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v') outputs seem to be corrupted

Tags: python, opencv, fastapi, video-processing

I have this function that basically takes a folder of frames and merges it to form a mp4 video

```
def frames_to_video(frames_path, fps, job_id, output_folder):
    """
    Compiles images from a specified folder into a video file at a given fps.
    """
    # Ensure the output folder exists
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    output_video_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{job_id}.mp4")

    frame_files = sorted([os.path.join(frames_path, f) for f in os.listdir(frames_path) if f.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'))])

    if not frame_files:
        print("No frames found in the specified path.")
        return

    # Read the first frame to determine the video size
    frame = cv2.imread(frame_files[0])
    if frame is None:
        print("Error reading the first frame.")
        return

    height, width, _ = frame.shape
    size = (width, height)

    # Define the codec and create a VideoWriter object
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')  # 'mp4v' for .mp4 output
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, fourcc, fps, size)

    for frame_file in frame_files:
        frame = cv2.imread(frame_file)
        if frame is None:
            print(f"Error reading frame: {frame_file}")
            continue
        # Write the frame to the video file
        out.write(frame)

    # Release the VideoWriter object
    out.release()

    print(f"Video saved to {output_video_path}")
```

Its seems to save the file correctly, however, VSCode isn't able to preview it (I have MPEG-Preview extension installed), if i download the video to my mac, its viewable. However the problems lies with if i try to stream it using something like FastAPI, its not viewable as well, it loads but isn't playable, its just a media player...

```
@app.get("/preview/{job_id}")
async def serve_video(job_id: str):
    video_path = os.path.join(f"{TEMP_STORAGE}/{job_id}", f"{job_id}.mp4")
    if not os.path.exists(video_path):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Video not found")
    return FileResponse(video_path, media_type="video/mp4")
```

Not sure if I'm making a mistake somewhere but I've tried quite a few of the suggested solutions, is there an alternative way to merge my frames?

Comment: do you know what "mp4v" is? ***no browser supports that video format.*** it's older than H.264. it does NOT describe a container format, even though you may think that.

Comment: pleast state all the relevant imports in your code, it would be actually better to proviede versions of both python and the library you are using

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That would explain it, I wasnt aware of that. To provide a bit more context, I'm working on a computer vision demo project that allows users to upload their own video, in the backend it splits that video into frames, runs inference on each frame and kinda combines the processed frames back into a video. The web application then shows a preview of the video which i did by 'streaming' it. That would kinda explain why the processed video can be viewed if i downloaded it to my local machine but does not work in browser. I'm kinda lost as to how I should preview it on web

Comment: @pippo1980 Python version 3.10.13, opencv is 4.8.1.78, i think the issue comes down to the ffmpeg encoder? I'm struggling to figure out how to install libx264 which was recommended by a lot of solutions...

Comment: you could choose a different codec (h.264, assuming your opencv-python comes with ffmpeg library that contains x264). or you could do what every beginner does and "stream" jpegs with `multipart/x-mixed-replace` transmission. answers for that are all over the internet.